# Infopaht form with simple code cannot be published, no domain controller, Sandbox Service and User code host service both started

Tags: infopath

I got the error message "The sandboxed solution could not be activated" when publishing an new empty infopath form with the default autogenerated c# code.

The Sharepoint 2010 User Code Host Running service is shown as started in the Windows Server console

The Sandboxed Code Service is Started in the Central Admin.

I can publish a form without code with no problems, and I also published with sucess a workflow .wsp as a solution amd activated it on the server.

There is no DC on the server.

Anyone have a clue on what could go wrong ?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reference [Error when deploying InfoPath web-enabled form (custom code in the form cannot be run)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35927/error-when-deploying-infopath-web-enabled-form-custom-code-in-the-form-cannot-b/36339#comment33085_36339) and see if anything there helps you solve this.

(First and foremost though I would confirm that the form is set as full-trust under security and trust)

Comment: Yes indeed I succedded in publishing the form with the full-trust setting. Here is a post which describes the steps required to do so http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/17702/61700.aspx   look for the comment in the middle of the post from user shrirampophali. Thanx Zork !